# Blender crashes when entering rendered view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I recently downloaded Blender 2.8 on my Windows 7 PC. Whenever I try to enter rendered or textured view, Blender crashes.

Comment: It has a command console, where it tells you what error is happening, or take a screenshot of the problem, if possible a gif would help much more

Comment: Please check if your computer fulfills the minimum requirements to run Blender 2.8 (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). Most importantly check if your graphics card is supported. If it is, try to update the graphics driver.